# How to Screen Capture With Own android Service without Rooted Device?

Tags: android

I have searched a lot and find two libraries for it.

1-https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library

2-https://github.com/rtyley/android-screenshot-lib

but still i can't able to use this code as i want.

There are some applications those are using such facility like-
**Screen Capture -No Rooting 2.2** on google play.

So here can anyone helps me??

Comment: is there anyone who knows about it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Please explain.

Comment: David Wasser Actually i want to take screen shot using the broadcast receiver,which will take screen shots after a particular time. please help if possible.

Comment: You do understand that this only works if the phone is connected to a PC and you've enabled USB debugging?

Comment: @NitishSrivastava I have the same problem did you find solution ?

Comment: @JFouad no,actually din't got at that time and not trying this time.

Answer (score 0):

For Lollipop onward you can use [Android MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html).