# Pending intent is not working

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am  using the pending intent in activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 34433,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (5000), pendingIntent);
```

here i am going from one activity(MainActivity) to another activity(MyActivity).
but it is not working.

if i try to do it with simple Intent then it works fine.

Comment: is your MyActivity extends Activity ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have requested a `PendingIntent` to start a `BroadcastReceiver`, but you are trying to start an `Activity`. This can't work.

If you want to start an `Activity`, instead of this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 34433,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

do this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 34433,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: David Wassser Can you help me on this??   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865986/how-to-screen-capture-with-own-android-service-without-rooted-device

Answer (score 0):

You can also use broadcast receiver with PendingIntent to start another activity.

create another class for example receiver as sub class of the BroadcastReceiver

```
public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
        // code to start another activity
         Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(intent);
     }
  }
```

and define MyActivity  as receiver in android menifest file
and in main activity change this code 
MyActivity.class to receiver.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, receiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 34433,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + (5000), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: yes i have also done the same but what about with the activity?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class); will start myactivity from receiver